# FB.Canvas.getPageInfo scrollTop broken on page tabs

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using `FB.Canvas.getPageInfo()` to figure out how far the user has scrolled.

```
FB.Canvas.getPageInfo( function(info) {
  console.log( info.scrollTop );
});
```

This code works when I load the app on the regular canvas (apps.facebook.com/appname) but prints `0` when the app is loaded inside a page tab.

Is this broken by accident or by design? Is there a workaround?

**Edit:** I've filed a [bug report](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/254969654586483) with Facebook.

Comment: Sounds like a great candidate for a bug.  There's currently not one there that I can find http://developers.facebook.com/bugs to log the issue with Facebook.

Comment: I was waiting a while for a possible answer before considering this a bug. Here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/254969654586483